# Cross-compile with relative pathnames - for binary portability/embeddability? (GCC)

Tags: gcc, compiler-construction, embedded, cross-platform, portability

Say I am creating an application bundle with some scripts, maybe a daemon, or even a helper binary...  When compiling such a binary.. is it feasible to ./configure/make it with only **relative** paths?  For example, a more conscientious Makefile will include for provisions such as...

```
--bindir=DIR           user executables [EPREFIX/bin]
--sbindir=DIR          system admin executables [EPREFIX/sbin]
--libexecdir=DIR       program executables [EPREFIX/libexec]
--sysconfdir=DIR       read-only single-machine data [PREFIX/etc]
--sharedstatedir=DIR   modifiable architecture-independent data [PREFIX/com]
--localstatedir=DIR    modifiable single-machine data [PREFIX/var]
--libdir=DIR           object code libraries [EPREFIX/lib]
--includedir=DIR       C header files [PREFIX/include]
--oldincludedir=DIR    C header files for non-gcc [/usr/include]
--datarootdir=DIR      read-only arch.-independent data root [PREFIX/share]
--datadir=DIR          read-only architecture-independent data [DATAROOTDIR]
--infodir=DIR          info documentation [DATAROOTDIR/info]
--localedir=DIR        locale-dependent data [DATAROOTDIR/locale]
--mandir=DIR           man documentation [DATAROOTDIR/man]
--docdir=DIR           documentation root [DATAROOTDIR/doc/hiawatha]
--htmldir=DIR          html documentation [DOCDIR]
--dvidir=DIR           dvi documentation [DOCDIR]
--pdfdir=DIR           pdf documentation [DOCDIR]
--psdir=DIR            ps documentation [DOCDIR]
```

This is great, you can install everything to `/opt/local` instead of `/usr/local`.  Maybe even go crazy, and rename the binaries via `sed`.. I get it..

But what remains unclear in my tiny brain, is **if the ability to arbitrarily set paths in such a manner extends to the ability to map the directories relative to the executable**, in a manner similar to...

```
--prefix=PREFIX    install architecture-independent files in PREFIX [/usr/local]
--prefix=./        aka  [../relative/to/binary]
```

So, for example, no matter where you launched the `bin` from, it would always know that it's `.conf` file was going to be up one folder, in the that relative `../etc` folder, or possibly even right next to it, in the same directory, `./`.  Similarly, you could guarantee write access to log and pid files, etc, without wondering about your target's permissions/directory structure...

This would enable a completely portable `/bin /etc /lib /var` directory structure, within a PATH to which I can guarantee some semblance of predictability...  but I don't think it just "works" like that..  And I am unsure if simply "linking statically" or otherwise ? truly creates binaries that are able to be moved to another system (*albeit, for this scenario, to ones with the same support libs in the same places, so as not to muddle the issue*)  Is it possibly to cross-compile in this manner?  And can you build for multiple architectures in the same build cycle? (For example i386 AND x86_64 at the same time)

Maybe I could just use a recommendation of a good GNU/GCC primer ( CC, CFLAGS, LDFLAGS, -l, , -I , and CPP 101, etc.)  but that wasn't written for (and by) Math teachers - in the 70's?

Answer (score 0):

In full generality, no, that won't work.  There are things in /etc for example that are expected to be shared by the whole system and won't work correctly if you're trying to keep a private copy for one app.

With that said, your app probably isn't using every single shared resource on the system.  Either using a local /bin and /sbin, or symlinking to the real ones from a relative path within your app's directory should be fine.  /var seems less likely as something that your app needs to know about directly - anything stopping you from storing logs your own way, or using syslogd?